# how to add jQuery animation on background overlay

Tags: jquery, html, css

i creating newsletter popup

My website is :
http://daplonline.in/ when home page load it show image popup of top student with **BLACK Overlay Colour** i want to add effect in overlay div like this any way to add this on my website

I want to add this Snow effect on overlay backgroud

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?GKBtfF4Q

Thank you

Comment: I can't trigger my JS in console at your website. :( Try this while showing overlay $('#wd1_nlpopup_overlay').snow({ SnowImage: "snow.gif" });

Answer (score 0):

i have done it in jsfiddle for you. Check the below link.

```
$(function(){ $('#openModal').snow({ SnowImage:   "http://jqsnow.sourceforge.net/snow/snow.gif",Quantity:7,HideSnowTime:0,ZIndexStart:0}); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qC85z/